# How to enable alt tag for the E commerce product page images in Magento?

Tags: configurable-product, meta-tags, ecommerce-tracking

I am using the Magento for my http://www.thelabellife.com/ website and I can not add the alt tag for all images on the product pages.
I have discussed with developer team as well, they are saying it is not possible that we can integrate backend code alt access in Magento.
Kindly help me on that, can I integrate alt images with the back end coding so that I can give the different names for the purpose of better search result in search engines?

Answer (score 0):

In Default Magento is possible :

You can try this way for single product yourself :)

1. Go to Admin->Catalog->Manage Product
2. Open any product then go to **images** tab
3. Now Just add lable for the images.
   This label will be taken as **alt** & **title** by **Default Magento**

Later you can ask the development team to upload labels in bulk for all your product images.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot. I am using E-commerce website, I just have a query if I haven't added any name in the label as specified by you above, still one image is showing product name as a alt image, how?  I am elaborating this- as in e-commerce site on product pages we have many 4 to 5 images available , actually i want to insert different searchable keywords as name for SEO practice so can I do that, would it be recommended?

Comment: To bulk upload image alts, you can use the Magento API:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeMedia/catalog_product_attribute_media.update.html